# How to get a provided service from shared library in AppModule level? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, ng-modules

Im trying to create a Guard service to authenticate my routes. But my guard service are located in a shared library.

This is my guard service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

Provided at shared modules:

```
import {RouteGuard} from './auth/guard/route.guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule],
  exports: [MaterialModule],
  providers: [RouteGuard]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And now i need to get this provided service at app module. How can i do that?

```
import {SharedModule} from '@acn-collections-ws/shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AuthComponent, LoggedComponent, HomeComponent, LoginComponent, SigninComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule, SharedModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
    AuthComponent,
    LoggedComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SigninComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

i need to import this service in my app routing module, and use with canActivate route validator. Like this:

```
// i cant found RouteGuard at acn-collections-ws/shared
import { RouteGuard } from '@acn-collections-ws/shared';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoggedComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
    ],
    canActivate: [RouteGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent}
    ]
  }

];
```

Comment: Why are you looking in  `'@acn-collections-ws/shared'` for `RouteGuard` ? Isni't from `'some_way/auth/guard/route.guard'` ?

Comment: my guard are located at shared library `@acn-collections-ws/shared`

Comment: im using a @nwrl library --preset=angular. With this, i can import external libs with @

Comment: Will you be able to create a minimal verifiable [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) example?

Comment: im gonna try to do that, today, later. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule],
  exports: [MaterialModule],
  providers: [RouteGuard]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

from the index.ts of shared library i need to export guard.module. (I was not exporting guard module).

```
export * from './lib/guard.module';
```

And know it worked

```
// Service guard
import {RouteGuard} from '@acn-collections-ws/shared';
```